# Why "this" refers to Window in forEach in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I run this code, window object gets printed to console.

```
var arr= [1,2,34,5,6,7,7,8];
arr.forEach(function(e){
console.log(this);
});
```

Why does it not refer to arr object or specific items in array object? I want to understand the reason behind it, like what's going on. `this` gets defined using by `new`, or the object invoking this function, right?

Comment: It happens because that's how `forEach` invokes it.

Comment: "why does this happen?" "because it happens" is not a good comment ;)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't see how your comment is relevant. If one wanted to know why this was chosen as a default behaviour - they should have asked a different questsion.

Comment: i specifically said **i want to understand the reason behind it** as in code structure and that leads to it

Comment: @zerkms and that question would be closed, because we weren't there when it was decided. I'm with you; the implementation could have defaulted to having `this` be the current element (like jQuery's `each`) or the array itself, but it doesn't, and it pretty much _doesn't matter why_.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer evey question about JS like "why it behaves like it behaves" have the same and the only answer: because the specification tells it to do so.

Comment: @Mathletics that sounds a completely valid question why would you close it? It'd be insightful for new programmer to know of reasoning behind some decision made about the design of language.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer as I said, __we were not there when the spec was written__, nor when it was implemented in the browser. Speculation on the nature of language idiosyncrasies is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: dont speculate if you don't know, but if you know say so. For one to have information one doesn't have to be a participant in creation of it or be present there. Inability to come up with a solid answer doesn't make the question bad.

Comment: and as i said my question is asking two things a) why did people do it like this ( their reasoning) b) how is this the result of its implementation, programmatically? what code makes it point to window object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) specifies the value of `this` within the iterator based on its 2nd parameter, `thisArg`.

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

So, it will only use a particular object if you provide it:

```
arr.forEach(function(e){
    console.log(this);
}, arr); // <---
```

Otherwise, the value of `this` will be the default value of a normal function call -- either `undefined` in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) or the global object (`window` in browsers) in non-strict.

```
function foo(e) {
    console.log(this);
}

foo();            // [object Window]

[1].forEach(foo); // (same)
```

---

Though, the `arr` is still provided to the iterator, just as its 3rd argument:

```
arr.forEach(function (e, i, arr) {
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This comes from two different factors of how the engine will determine the `this` value for the function, the `thisArg` optional parameter to `forEach`, and whether or not the code is in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `forEach()`, it will be passed to `callback` when invoked, for use as its `this` value.  Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be passed for use as its `this` value. The `this` value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to *the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function*.

These rules are [elsewhere documented as follows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.
>
> ```
> function f1(){
>   return this;
> }
>
> f1() === window; // global object
> ```
>
> In this case, the value of `this` is not set by the call. Since the code is **not in strict mode**, the value of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object. (emphasis added)

Note that this behavior changes in strict mode. If you add `"use strict"` to the top of the call back, it will log `undefined` to the console.

In short, if you want the `this` value to refer to the array, `arr`, you just need to call `forEach` like this:

```
var arr= [1,2,34,5,6,7,7,8];
arr.forEach(function(e){
    console.log(this);
}, arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) says so. Relevant parts:

> #### 15.4.4.18 Array.prototype.forEach ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )
>
> ...
>
> 5. If *thisArg* was supplied, let *T* be *thisArg*; else let *T* be **undefined**.
>
> ...
>
> 7.c.ii Call the [[Call]] internal method of *callbackfn* with *T* as the **this** value and argument list containing *kValue*, *k*, and *O*.

Now, we all know (hopefully) that if a function is to be called with a `this` value of `null` or `undefined`, `this` is set to the global object instead. Here is a [refresher](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3):

> #### 10.4.3 Entering Function Code
>
> 1. If the function code is [strict code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1), set the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to *thisArg*.
> 2. Else if *thisArg* is **null** or **undefined**, set the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to the global object.
> 3. ...

As you can also see, `this` will not point to the global object if we are not in strict mode (the default).

---

> I want to understand the reason behind it

Why it was decided to do it this way can likely only be explained by someone who worked on the language. You could ask at https://esdiscuss.org or http://es-discourse.com/.

Answer (score 2):

> `this` gets defined using by `new`, or the object invoking this function, right?

[Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). And in this case, it's `forEach` that invokes your function. Since no special precautions<sup>[1]</sup> are made, it simply passes nothing for `this`<sup>[2]</sup> just like any non-method function call, which will result into the global object as your function is sloppy code<sup>[3]</sup>.

<sub>1: Like passing a [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters) to `forEach`, which would be used for `this`

2: [The spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18) says it should pass `undefined`

3: Meaning, that it does not use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). In strict code, `this` would literally really be `undefined`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The function you've passed into forEach does not have the same context as your object. The `forEach` (as well as `map` etc) functions run detached from any object, so functions passed into them are executed in global scope by default.

You could be explicit and fix that in one of two ways.

1. give the forEach a context to run in (as suggested by every other answer)

This uses code like:

```
var arr = [...];
var iterator = function(e) { console.log(this); };
arr.forEach(iterator, this);
```

2. make your iteration function explicitly bound to your object first

this uses code like:

```
var arr = [...];
var iterator = function(e) { console.log(this); };
var iteratorWithThisContext = iterator.bind(this);
arr.forEach(iteratorWithThisContext);
```

The `bind(<context>)` function is a core javascript function for taking any function, and any context, and returning a new function that will always execute with the specified context when called, no matter who's doing the calling, or when:

```
var fn = function() { console.log(this); }
fn(); // window

var fndoc = fn.bind(document);
fndoc(); // document

var arr = [];
var fnarr = fn.bind(arr);
fnarr(); // the array
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach(), it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function.

If you expect `this` to be the array, you have to call `arr.forEach(function(e){}, arr);` using the *optional* second paramater, `thisArg`.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's very interesting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

You can include a second argument for the `this` object when calling `forEach`.  If not provided, `this` will be limited to the same scope as if you were simply to write `for (var i in arr) {.. }`.  I suspect they did this so that the `forEach` function behaves as closely to a built-in syntactical feature of JS as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function being called here is not being called as an object method, `this` refers to the current object context, and in a browser console window, that's the `window` object.

This [Mozilla Developer Network article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) goes into great depth about what `this` means in different contexts.